# Php echo $_POST with a variable

Tags: php, validation, post, echo

I'm trying to display a `$_POST` that has a variable within.

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php if ($options) { ?>
<?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
<?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
<textarea name="<?php echo $option['name']; ?>" rows="1" cols="20" class=""><?php echo '$_POST['.$option['name'].']' ?></textarea>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

So far I'm able to display the `$option['name']` variable.So, for `<?php echo '$_POST['.$option['name'].']' ?>`, I get `$_POST[size]` for exemple in the textarea.

Any idea how to work this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables inside single quotes are not parsed due to variable interpolation.

What you can do is:

Replace

```
<?php echo '$_POST['.$option['name'].']' ?>
```

By

```
<?php echo $_POST[$option['name']]; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found error between textarea

change this line

```
<?php echo '$_POST['.$option['name'].']' ?>
```

to this

```
<?php echo $_POST[$option['name']] ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this line**

```
 <?php echo $_POST[$option['name']] ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
if($options) {
    foreach($options as $option) {
        if($option['type'] == 'select')
            echo '<textarea name="', $option['name'], '" rows="1" cols="20">', $_POST[$option['name']], '</textarea>', "\n";
    }
}
```